# Emacs `message` function doesn't update *Messages* automatically when called from an SMIE rules-function

Tags: emacs, elisp, smie

I have two buffers open in Emacs, each in their own window, and one of those buffers is the `*Messages*` buffer (for the sake of example, let's say the other buffer is `*scratch*`). Most things printed to the echo area are immediately visible in the `*Messages*` buffer. In other words, if I'm in `*scratch*` and press `C-g` then "Quit" is printed to the `*Messages*` buffer right away. If I enter `(message "hi")` into the `*scratch*` buffer and `eval` it, the `*Messages*` buffer is also updated right away.

However, when I try to call the `message` function from an [SMIE](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html#SMIE) `rules-function`, the `*Messages*` buffer is not updated right away, and I have to switch to it (`C-x o`) in order to see it updated, or scroll it from the other buffer (`C-M-v`).

This is obviously trivial to work around, but printing stuff with `messages` is damn useful when debugging an SMIE indentation rules function, which is what I'm doing. When I hit `tab` in a particular place in my source code, sometimes this function is called more than once, with different parameters (`:before` and `:after` for the same token, for instance), resulting in more than one line printed to `*Messages*`.

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, and in actual fact the SMIE rules function should never be called more than once?? In that case I guess this would be a bug in the lexical spec for this SMIE mode? I'm fiddling with `sml-mode.el` and it's called twice when the point is on a line after a "definitional equals" for instance:

```
val x =
|
```

where the point is `|`

Comment: Maybe just code some switch buffers around the command in that mode (back and forth)? Should be instantly.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for the rules function to be called twice.  Not sure why the messages don't appear in *Messages* in the same way, but it's not due to SMIE doing something special about it.  To debug smie rules, I personally use Edebug (hit `C-u C-M-x` in the smie-rules function you need to debug).

Comment: Thanks for the comment about SMIE rules function, that actually helps a lot. For whatever reason, today my `*Messages*` buffer is now updating instantly... not sure what I did differently. But I will take a look at Edebug, that sounds like it would pay off.

Comment: I just realized you might be the author of SMIE and sml-mode.el... if so, thanks for those!